# How can I MOSFET DC parameter(Vto,kp,lmabda...) at LTSpice?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, ltspice, spice

[image]

I'm trying to simulate CS Amplifier with current mirror as SEDRA Book described.

It has such DC parameters (kp,vto,lambda...)

I selected monolithic MOSFET NMOS4, PMOS4, and I downloaded MOSFET models at this websites
(http://cmosedu.com/cmos1/book.htm)and included that Models.

And we can see the frequency response like a upper photo.

But, when I have added .model on text and typed DC parameters, It didn't seem to be applied.

I doubted It is because MOSFET model I have downloaded already have that parameters.

And I read that file and didn't find those parameters(kp,kn,Vto,lamba....)

How can I apply it?

I add the model parameters.

---

```
* Short channel models from CMOS Circuit Design, Layout, and Simulation,

* 50nm BSIM4 models VDD=1V, see CMOSedu.com

*

.model  N_50n  nmos  level = 54

+binunit = 1            paramchk= 1            mobmod  = 0          

+capmod  = 2            igcmod  = 1            igbmod  = 1            geomod  = 0          

+diomod  = 1            rdsmod  = 0            rbodymod= 1            rgatemod= 1          

+permod  = 1            acnqsmod= 0            trnqsmod= 0          

+tnom    = 27           toxe    = 1.4e-009     toxp    = 7e-010       toxm    = 1.4e-009   

+epsrox  = 3.9          wint    = 5e-009       lint    = 1.2e-008   

+ll      = 0            wl      = 0            lln     = 1            wln     = 1          

+lw      = 0            ww      = 0            lwn     = 1            wwn     = 1          

+lwl     = 0            wwl     = 0            xpart   = 0            toxref  = 1.4e-009   

+vth0    = 0.22         k1      = 0.35         k2      = 0.05         k3      = 0          

+k3b     = 0            w0      = 2.5e-006     dvt0    = 2.8          dvt1    = 0.52       

+dvt2    = -0.032       dvt0w   = 0            dvt1w   = 0            dvt2w   = 0          

+dsub    = 2            minv    = 0.05         voffl   = 0            dvtp0   = 1e-007     

+dvtp1   = 0.05         lpe0    = 5.75e-008    lpeb    = 2.3e-010     xj      = 2e-008     

+ngate   = 5e+020       ndep    = 2.8e+018     nsd     = 1e+020       phin    = 0          

+cdsc    = 0.0002       cdscb   = 0            cdscd   = 0            cit     = 0          

+voff    = -0.15        nfactor = 1.2          eta0    = 0.15         etab    = 0          

+vfb     = -0.55        u0      = 0.032        ua      = 1.6e-010     ub      = 1.1e-017   

+uc      = -3e-011      vsat    = 1.1e+005     a0      = 2            ags     = 1e-020     

+a1      = 0            a2      = 1            b0      = -1e-020      b1      = 0          

+keta    = 0.04         dwg     = 0            dwb     = 0            pclm    = 0.18       

+pdiblc1 = 0.028        pdiblc2 = 0.022        pdiblcb = -0.005       drout   = 0.45       

+pvag    = 1e-020       delta   = 0.01         pscbe1  = 8.14e+008    pscbe2  = 1e-007     

+fprout  = 0.2          pdits   = 0.2          pditsd  = 0.23         pditsl  = 2.3e+006   

+rsh     = 3            rdsw    = 150          rsw     = 150          rdw     = 150        

+rdswmin = 0            rdwmin  = 0            rswmin  = 0            prwg    = 0          

+prwb    = 6.8e-011     wr      = 1            alpha0  = 0.074        alpha1  = 0.005      

+beta0   = 30           agidl   = 0.0002       bgidl   = 2.1e+009     cgidl   = 0.0002     

+egidl   = 0.8          

+aigbacc = 0.012        bigbacc = 0.0028       cigbacc = 0.002

+nigbacc = 1            aigbinv = 0.014        bigbinv = 0.004        cigbinv = 0.004

+eigbinv = 1.1          nigbinv = 3            aigc    = 0.017        bigc    = 0.0028

+cigc    = 0.002        aigsd   = 0.017        bigsd   = 0.0028       cigsd   = 0.002

+nigc    = 1            poxedge = 1            pigcd   = 1            ntox    = 1

+xrcrg1  = 12           xrcrg2  = 5          

+cgso    = 6.238e-010   cgdo    = 6.238e-010   cgbo    = 2.56e-011    cgdl    = 2.495e-10     

+cgsl    = 2.495e-10    ckappas = 0.02         ckappad = 0.02         acde    = 1          

+moin    = 15           noff    = 0.9          voffcv  = 0.02       

+kt1     = -0.21        kt1l    = 0.0           kt2     = -0.042        ute     = -1.5

+ua1     = 1e-009       ub1     = -3.5e-019     uc1     = 0             prt     = 0

+at      = 53000

+fnoimod = 1            tnoimod = 0          

+jss     = 0.0001       jsws    = 1e-011       jswgs   = 1e-010       njs     = 1          

+ijthsfwd= 0.01         ijthsrev= 0.001        bvs     = 10           xjbvs   = 1          

+jsd     = 0.0001       jswd    = 1e-011       jswgd   = 1e-010       njd     = 1          

+ijthdfwd= 0.01         ijthdrev= 0.001        bvd     = 10           xjbvd   = 1          

+pbs     = 1            cjs     = 0.0005       mjs     = 0.5          pbsws   = 1          

+cjsws   = 5e-010       mjsws   = 0.33         pbswgs  = 1            cjswgs  = 5e-010     

+mjswgs  = 0.33         pbd     = 1            cjd     = 0.0005       mjd     = 0.5        

+pbswd   = 1            cjswd   = 5e-010       mjswd   = 0.33         pbswgd  = 1          

+cjswgd  = 5e-010       mjswgd  = 0.33         tpb     = 0.005        tcj     = 0.001      

+tpbsw   = 0.005        tcjsw   = 0.001        tpbswg  = 0.005        tcjswg  = 0.001      

+xtis    = 3            xtid    = 3          

+dmcg    = 0e-006       dmci    = 0e-006       dmdg    = 0e-006       dmcgt   = 0e-007     

+dwj     = 0e-008       xgw     = 0e-007       xgl     = 0e-008     

+rshg    = 0.4          gbmin   = 1e-010       rbpb    = 5            rbpd    = 15         

+rbps    = 15           rbdb    = 15           rbsb    = 15           ngcon   = 1
```

Comment: You already [have an answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/561979/95619).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen you mean it is a right way to give mosfet DC parameters by typing '.model N_50n nmos(kp=65u....)' .... But graph doesn't change regardless of that sentences. do you know what is the problem?

Comment: You're using two definitions for `N_50n`.  They are fighting with each other and one is winning.  The one in the text file is for LEVEL=54, and the `.model` SPICE directive on your schematic is for LEVEL=1.  Delete the `.include cmosedu_models.txt` on your schematic to remove the contradiction.

Comment: @SteKulov If I delete '.include_cmosedu_models.txt' , DC MOSFET Parameters are applied, but it seems other parameters are not. ac response flat curve is flat. how can I put not only DC parameters but also AC parameters?

Comment: @fluencer You need to add LEVEL1 AC parameters to your `.model` statement.  See the LTspice help (press `F1` key on keyboard) and reference the parameter table in the [M. MOSFET](http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/M_MOSFET.htm) section.  Start by playing around with all the parameters in that table that begin with a `C`.

Comment: @SteKulov I think you are gonna instruct me changing MOSFET internal parastic capacitances... It's very hard to control the values, so I decided just using DC parameters, and If I wanna see more detail ac response I'd using other existing Part. Thanks